# Another question about a formula in the book by Green, Schwarz, Witten

Tags: operators, string-theory

In formula 2.2.62 of Green Schwarz Witten:
$$
(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^m\,k\cdot\alpha_{m-n}\,e^{i\, n \,\tau})V(k,\tau)\tag{2.2.62}.
$$
I am having a problem working out the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. Let us write:
$$
V(k,0)=\exp{(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-1}}{1}+\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-2}}{2}\dots)}\exp{(-\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{1}}{1}-\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{2}}{2}\dots)}
$$
We then get:
$$
[L_4,V]=[L_4, \exp(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-1}}{1})\,]\exp{(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-2}}{2}+\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-3}}{3}+\dots)}+ \exp(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-1}}{1})\,[L_4,\exp{(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-2}}{2})}\,]\, \exp(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-3}}{3}+\dots)+\dots
$$
We can write out the first term in the above expression using formula 2.2.61:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\,k\cdot\alpha_{3}\, \exp(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-1}}{1})\,+\,\exp(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-1}}{1})\,k\cdot\alpha_{3})\exp{(\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-2}}{2}+\frac{k\cdot\alpha_{-3}}{3}+\dots)}
$$
Since $\alpha_3\,,\alpha_{-1}$ commute, this can be written:
$$
k\cdot\alpha_{3}\,V
$$
This is the first term in 2.2.62 above with the factor of one half missing.

Comment: Detailed reference? What is the context here, what do the symbols mean?!